# Django : Know if property is the default value

Tags: django, django-models

How can you know if a value is the default value for a Model's property.

For example

```
class Alias(models.Model) :
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='alias', default='/media/alias-default.png')

a = Alias.get("123")
# this doesn't work
if a.image == a.image.default :
  pass
# nor this
if a.image == Alias.image.default :
  pass
```

I tried digging in the docs, but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` in Django is not the same as SQL default - it's there merely for admin to auto-fill the form field on new object creation.

If you want to compare something to value defined as `default` you have to define it somewhere else (i.e. in `settings.py`). Like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    my_field = models.IntegerField(default=settings.INT_DEFAULT)
```

The `default` value is stored in `MyModel._meta._fields()[field_creation_index].default` but be aware that this is digging in internals.

Comment: Anything with name beginning with underscore should be considered internal. Anyway, it did not change between 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: If you want to use the internal attribute (_meta is quite stable for internal API), it's easier to read MyModel._meta.get_field('field_name').default rather than accessing by creation index.

Comment: Sure, I didn't even know such method exists for Meta. I always used fields() for iteration over the complete list of fields, never tried to access single field attributes. :)

Comment: `_meta` has been formalized in Django 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/

Comment: @furins Thank you, this is the information I needed! But here's a static link to the version you're referring to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/

Answer (score 3):

You can't get it from the property itself, you have to go via the model options under `model._meta`.

```
a._meta.get_field_by_name('image')[0].get_default()
```

Comment: Is that supported or might change going forward?