# How do I get the default value for a field in a Django model?

Tags: django, model, default

I have a Django model with some fields that have default values specified.  I am looking to grab the default value for one of these fields for us later on in my code.  Is there an easy way to grab a particular field's default value from a model?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the field like this:

```
myfield = MyModel._meta.get_field_by_name('field_name')
```

and the default is just an attribute of the field:

```
myfield.default
```

Comment: Anything with a _ is digging into the internals. See my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011946/django-know-if-property-is-the-default-value

Comment: Nowadays the `get_field_by_name` method returns a tuple with the field object as its first item.

Comment: @PaulTarjan you are right, but the `_meta` is one of those well-established, not-too-likely to change elements. The general consensus is that it is OK to access a model's `_meta` directly.

Comment: field.default might be a callable. Should use get_default()

Comment: Down voting because this is currently out of date.

Comment: Down voted because it's currently out of date. Should do TheModel._meta.get_field('the_field').get_default()

Comment: `.default` does not always return the default (e.g. it might be `NOT_PROVIDED`). `.get_default()` is much more reliable.

Answer (score 88):

```
TheModel._meta.get_field('the_field').get_default()
```

Comment: This is the best answer. `.get_default()` is much more reliable, whereas `.default` does not always return the default (e.g. it might be `NOT_PROVIDED`).

Answer (score 27):

As of Django 1.9.x you may use:

```
field = TheModel._meta.get_field('field_name')
default_value = field.get_default()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to write the field name explicitly, you can also do this:
`MyModel._meta.get_field(MyModel.field.field_name).default`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the default values for more than one field (e.g. in some kind of reinitialization step) it may be worth to just instantiate a new temporary object of your model and use the field values from that object.

```
temp_obj = MyModel()
obj.field_1 = temp_obj.field_1 if cond_1 else 'foo'
...
obj.field_n = temp_obj.field_n if cond_n else 'bar'
```

Of course this is only worth it, if the temporary object can be constructed without further performance / dependency issues.