# django get default model field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to write a view to reset some model field values to their default. How can I get default model field values?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar_field = models.CharField(blank=True, default='bar')
```

so what I want is:

```
def reset(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Foo, id=id)
    obj.bar_field = # logic to get default from model field
    obj.save()
    ...
```

Comment: Be more specific, what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: updated @SebastianBurzyński

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308332/how-do-i-get-the-default-value-for-a-field-in-a-django-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myfield = Foo._meta.get_field_by_name('bar_field')
```

and the default is just an attribute of the field:

```
myfield.default
```

Comment: Actually it's myfield = Foo._meta.get_field('bar_field') but you point me to the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: deprecated in Django 1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#module-django.db.models.options

Answer (score 3):

Since Django 1.10: `myfield = Foo._meta.get_field('bar_field').get_default()`

see here (not explained in the Docs apparently...) : [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L2301](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2301)